# React state is not updating immediately for first time

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-redux, frontend

I am supposed to show the text "**I am visible**" on toggling the button means  means when someone click on it for first time it should show text then if click again it should be hidden and then again if someone click on button it should be visible like that.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  let length = 0;
  const handleOpen = () => {
    if (length === 0) {
      setOpen(false);
    } else {
      setOpen(true);
    }
    length++;
  };
  return (
    <>
      {open && <div> I am visible </div>}
      <button onClick={handleOpen}> change visibility </button>
    </>
  );
};
export default App;
```

I the code above I have to click two time simultaneously to show the text and one time to hide it. If you know the solution please share your valuable suggestions.

Comment: you will know why by console.log(length)

Comment: When I am doing it in following way. It's working can someone explain why ?

https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-tdd-xx398t?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(!open);
  };
  return (
    <>
      {open && <div> I am visible </div>}
      <button onClick={handleOpen}> change visibility </button>
    </>
  );
};
export default App;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-jerry-ig46ct?file=/src/App.js:0-318